# Cutting strings to 'variable' long chunks

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have looked into this problem, but I couldn't find a good answer. So here is my code:

```
var str = '000100111000010110'
var length = 2;
var temp = new Array(str.match(/.{length}/g));
```

But this doesn't work.

It's very important to keep the length of a variable, and if I don't have to, I won't use a regular expression.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: an array which contains 00, 01, 10 or 11 in every of its items

Comment: Actually, I was looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript), but my little understanding of the problem led to not asking the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a regular `for` loop and `substr`. No need to involve regex where it isn't needed:

```
var str = '000100111000010110';
var length = 2;

var split = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i += length) {
    split.push(str.substr(i, length));
}

console.log(split);
// ["00", "01", "00", "11", "10", "00", "01", "01", "10"]
```